# How can I create an HTML file which I can include in other HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, html

If we want to run the same html header code on several pages, can we have a external html file or link to the existing header code instead of having the same code written in every page?

Comment: If you're using a backend language, it would be preferable for you to do it server side rather than client side. If you're using PHP, you can use [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: I was going to suggest that doing this via JS is generally a really bad idea for common pieces.  You should probably use a server-side framework or generation tool for this.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it with jquery. Put this code in index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("header.html"); 
  $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<!--Remaining section-->
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And put this code in header.html and footer.html at the same location as the index.html

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">click here for google</a>
```

Then visit the index.html, you should be able to click the link tags.

Comment: Some Documentation on it. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

You can use IFRAME to load content of any other HTML page in your current html page.

```
<html>
    <head>
        YOUR CSS GOES HERE
    </head>
    <body>
        ANY TEXT YOU WANT
        <iframe src="PATH TO OTHER HTML PAGE">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works, however, it isn't a very elegant way of including another file. It should be done server side via something like `include()`, or if need be, client side with something like @shas recommended.